# Meaning of "readily transferable"?

Tags: loans, deposits, terminology

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_instrument#Categorization):

> **Cash instruments** are financial
>   instruments whose value is determined
>   directly by markets. They can be
>   divided into **securities**, which are
>   readily transferable, and **other cash
>   instruments such as loans and
>   deposits**, where both borrower and
>   lender have to agree on a transfer.

I was wondering what "readily transferable" means? How is it different from "both borrower and lender have to agree on a transfer", i.e., don't securities require that "both borrower and lender have to agree on a transfer"?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3):

Securities or quite a few negotiable instruments can change title of ownership without any issue. Many at times the owner ship in implicit if you are holding a certain instrument. So for example in Stock its a fractional ownership in a company, this ownership transfers to the buyer from the seller without requiring any permission from the company.

In case of say Loans, One cannot transfer the loan to some one else without the Banks permission.